Can a prone player character use a disengage action in DnD 5e?
My pc has been knocked prone. On his turn can he disengage, crawl out of the enemies's melee range, then stand up ?

Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] in case you search for some guidance in posting Q&A here. Happy Gaming!

Is there a reason you would not stand up first, then take the disengage, and then walk out of the enemy's melee range?  It might help us answer this if we knew why you wanted to do this.

@Kirt OP said in comment to my answer where I explain this with rules quotations, and contrast it to 3.5e, where it did cause Attacks of Opportunity, that their DM plays it so that getting up from prone causes opportunity attacks — to wich this then is the reasonable countertactic.

The text of Disengage says:

If you take the Disengage action, your movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks for the rest of the turn.

There is no mention of different types of movement: regardless of how you are moving, taking the Disengage Action denies yours enemies to make Opportunity Attacks against you.
Remember anyway that your DM could rule otherwise, if the circumstances do not allow you to efficiently disengage from the combat.

You can if you have enough movement speed
...But you might want to consider getting up first.
Some things to consider

Getting up takes half of your speed, for simplicity lets assume this is your walking speed, and consider that for most characters this is 30' or 40'. So getting up will usually cost 15' or 20' of movement.
Crawling takes an additional foot of movement for every foot crawled. So if you're prone while 5' away, and your enemy has a reach of 5', then you disengage, then crawl 5' to get out of range (spending 10' of movement), then stand up (spending 15' or 20' of movement). Now you have 5' or 10' of movement left (depending on your speed) and you're 10' away from your enemy.
If the creature has a 10' reach, you might have a big problem. Now you disengage, then move 10' crawling (spending 20' of movement), if your move speed was 40' you can get up and can't move anymore, but if it was 30' now you can't get up.
If you're in difficult terrain and the creature has 10' reach, then crawling 10' takes 30' of movement, and you can't get up unless your speed was 60'.
Getting up usually doesn't provoke an attack of opportunity, and even if it did, your disengage action should take care of avoiding it. So, if  you disengage, then get up (spending half your movement) you can proceed to use the rest of your movement without any crawling speed penalties or opportunity attacks.


Yes, but standing up in 5e does not provoke opportunity attacks
You may be thinking of an earlier edition like D&D 3.5, where standing up from prone caused an opportunity attack

Standing up is a move-equivalent action that provokes an attack of opportunity.

So in that edition, you first wanted to get out of reach before standing up. This however is not the case any more in 5e. (PHB, p. 190)

Standing up takes more effort; doing so costs an amount of movement equal to half your speed. For example, if your speed is 30 feet, you must spend 15 feet of movement to stand up. You can’t stand up if you don’t have enough movement left or if your speed is 0.

There is no clause that it causes opportunity attacks. Therefore, you could just stand up first, disengage, and the move away farther (your other half remaining speed at normal cost) than if you crawled away because

To move while prone, you must crawl or use magic such as teleportation. Every foot of movement while crawling costs 1 extra foot.

That said, it does not matter how you move: when you disengage your movement will not cause opportunity attacks (PHB, p. 192)

If you take the Disengage action, your movement doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks for the rest of the turn.

Nothing here says this won't work when prone. So yes, you could disengage, crawl away and stand up without provoking. Its just not as efficient as doing it the other way round.

My DM uses op attacks on characters getting up from prone.

@TroyPrentice Ah, yes, that explains your motivation. Crawl away, then.

@TroyPrentice: Even if you disengage before standing up, to make op attacks impossible except for enemies with the Sentinel feat?  IDK, I haven't seen that house-rule in action in 5e so I don't know how your DM might be playing it.
